# app_dev not using updated parameters.yml

Tags: symfony

I was currently migrating the data from my temporary oracle DB to the definitive one. While changing parameters.yml and being in prod mode I got an error so I wanted to check on dev mode. I went and cleared the cache for the dev mode and dumped assetic, etc; but app_dev is still using the parameters.yml config from my temporary database rather than the new one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the prod cache folder and then cleared cache with app/console. It worked